# css dropdown menu override child li's properties

Tags: html, css

First of all i would like to add that its been a while, about 3 years, since i've developed a dropdown menu in CSS. I have this drop down menu, but i have the following issue. apparently i cannot override properties of li/a elements of my submenu.

I would like to make the font color of submenu's li's a elements same as color of menu's ul's li's a elements, which is light grey ( rgb(206,206,204) )

Could somebody please take a look and point me at what i am doing wrong? Here's a link to a source code archive with html, css and background images:
http://www.filedropper.com/001_17

Comment: Not going to download your file, I suggest making a fiddle.

Comment: i did not make a fiddle as, correct me if i'm wrong, i will not be able to link images with css.

Comment: We do not need the images to make your dropdown work, just the code. And you could always put them online(imgur) and just update the src in your fiddle

Comment: This might be a solution. thank you for your suggestion anyway. but images here are quite important because of background clipping

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this rule:

```
div ul.menu li:hover a{

    background-color: rgb(73,144,241);

    background-color: rgba(73,144,241,0.05);

    color: rgb(255,255,255);

}
```

With that rule all `<a>`'s in that `<li>` turn white. What you need to do is have only the direct children turn white:

```
div ul.menu li:hover > a{

        background-color: rgb(73,144,241);

        background-color: rgba(73,144,241,0.05);

        color: rgb(255,255,255);

}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/4G7K3/)

Comment: Thank you! not only that solved my problem but actually finally explained me what the > operator in css is for. I really should have finished reading that css3 book.